Arima NaN Values
I have a dataset about the population from 1950 till 2100. The dataset was not stationary so I had to diff twice.
Differencing 1:
df_diff1 = df.diff() df_diff1 = df_diff1.dropna()
Differencing 2:
df_diff2 = df_diff1.diff() df_diff2 = df_diff2.dropna()
After that, I started building the ARIMA model
model = ARIMA(df_diff2['Population'], order = (2,2,3))
model_fit = model.fit()
print(model_fit.summary())

Train and test set:
train_size = int(len(df_diff2) * 0.8)
train, test = df_diff2[0:train_size], df_diff2[train_size:len(df)]
test_forecast = model_train_fit.get_forecast(steps=len(test))
test_forecast_series = pd.Series(test_forecast.predicted_mean, index=test.index)

Now df_diff2 does not contain any NaN values, but when running the following code:
mse = mean_squared_error(test['Population'], test_forecast_series)
rmse = mse**0.5

I receive the error ValueError: Input contains NaN.
Looking into it, it is indeed correct that test_forecast_series has 30 values and all values are NaN.
Where did it go wrong that I only have NaN values for test_forecast_series when running the test? The other column (test['Population']) has no NaN values.
Could someone help me out please?
I have tried changing the size of the test.
I have looked into other datasets but couldn't find anything that could help me
Chat GPT did not help either
